# Can't debug some applications in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-mac

When creating a new console application (.Net core) in Visual Studio for Mac and I try to debug it, I get an error:

> **Debugger operation failed**
>
> Unable to start debugging. The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an
>   exception.

This happens after updating the application to the latest stable release of `.Net core 1.1.0`.

Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Does the application run on the command line if you use `dotnet run`?

Comment: The error indicates that openssl is not installed or linked correctly. The instructions for the install on the Mac have been updated from the original at https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

Comment: @NateBarbettini yes it does

Comment: @JohnDavidson those were the instructions I used to install it. The error is displayed by Visual Studio, not the app. The app runs fine if started. Also, on some apps debugging works, on others it doesn't. I haven't yet been able to tell exactly what the difference is between apps that can be debugged and apps that can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following (found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1161) ):

```
brew update
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

Update: I have faced with the same problem after updating mono via brew. And repeating last steps from [Install pre-requisites](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) section helps...

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: Tried it before posting. It solved the problems with the applications not starting, but it didn't fix the problems with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in September/October, with Rider everything always worked.
I reported this bug on Xamarin bugzilla and immediately somebody contacted me and "we solved" (I let him working on my machine with TeamViewer).

[image]

The working version (7.4) is still not stable but it will be soon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure this location is set correctly:
[image]